# Не приходит команда старт боту

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Столкнулся с проблемой, что определённое время бот работает отлично, то есть такие моменты, что боту не приходит команда `start` уже проверял много раз, но не могу понять в чем проблема. Уже проверил и интернет соединение и много разных методов, но так и не понял.

Вот мой код

```
import telebot
import sqlite3
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    connect = sqlite3.connect("users.db")
    cursor = connect.cursor()

    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS login_id(id INTEGER)")
    connect.commit()

    user_id = [message.chat.id]
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO login_id VALUES(?);", user_id)
    connect.commit()

    sti = open('gangsta.jpg', 'rb')

    markup_reply = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True).add(
        "☎Меню", "Промо", "Наши проекты", "Инфо", " Наш чат")

    markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Купить номер', callback_data='buynumber'),
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Пополнить баланс', callback_data='balance')).add(
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Cтрана/Оператор', callback_data='country'),
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Мультисервис', callback_data='myltis')).add(
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='История покупок', callback_data='history')).add(
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Профиль', callback_data='prof'))


    bot.send_message(
        message.chat.id,
        'Выбери что тебе интересно',
        reply_markup=markup_reply)
    bot.send_photo(
        message.chat.id,
        photo=sti,
        caption=' Вотсап братка!\nТебя приветствует Gang SMS!\n Приятных покупок.',
        reply_markup=markup_inline)


bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что консоль пишет?

Answer (score -1):

Скорее всего специально, но всё же подсвечу, что не указан ТОКЕН при запуске бота

Если в консоли нет никакой инфы, то я бы проверил поочередно все функции, что запускаются этой командой (подключение к БД, открытие файла)

Если такого формата анализ не проканает, то лучше сделать  логирование программы при помощи библиотеки **logger**. Посмотреть, как пользоваться этой библиотекой можно в статье: https://habr.com/ru/company/wunderfund/blog/683880/

Необходимо настроить самый низкий уровень логирования (DEBUG), чтобы выводить все действия производимые программой. Это поможет выявить ошибку

Comment: Я думаю в его случае хватит простых принтов, чтобы понять на каком этапе ошибка